# Codable - arrayPropety [AnyObject]: Reference to member 'data' cannot be resolved without a contextual type

Tags: swift, generics, codable

Setting up Codable Class. The array of AnyObjects is creating a compilation error:

> Reference to member 'data' cannot be resolved without a contextual type

```
class ClassA<T>: NSObject, Codable {

    // MARK: - Properties

    let title: String
    let data: [T] // data is an array of either Codable objects of ClassB or ClassC. 

    // MARK: - Keyes

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case title
        case data
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        title = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .title)
        data = [T]()
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {

        var container = encoder.container(
            keyedBy: CodingKeys.self
        )

        try container.encode(title, forKey: .title)
        try container.encode(data, forKey: .data) // Compilation error: Reference to member 'data' cannot be resolved without a contextual type
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data type `T` must conform to `Encodable/Codable` change

```
class ClassA<T:Codable>: NSObject, Codable {
```

the compiler won't know whether the array generic element conform to `Encodable` or not , hence the error

Answer (score 1):

The `encode(_:, forKey:)` method needs a type conforming to `Encodable`, otherwise how could it know how to encode that input argument? So you either need to change your generic type parameter to require `Encodable`/`Codable` conformance or don't encode the `data` variable if it doesn't need to be part of your JSON (as it seems it isn't part of the decoded JSON anyways).

Simply make `ClassB` and `ClassC` conform to `Codable` too and then changing the type constraint won't be an issue and you won't even need the custom `init(from:)` and `encode(to:)` methods.

```
class ClassA<T: Codable>: Codable {

    // MARK: - Properties
    let title: String
    let data: [T] // data is an array of either Codable objects of ClassB or ClassC. 
}
```

Unrelated to your issue, but you shouldn't make Swift classes inherit from `NSObject` unless you need it for Obj-C interoperability. Swift classes don't need to inherit from a base class unlike in Obj-C.